# Doctrine ODM MongoDB EmbedOne Document not loaded

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm, odm

I need to store some data for our booking and thats include the customer data, which I want as embedded document within my booking document. With my current configuration all data are persisted in MongoDB, but when I load the booking document, there is no related customer object. Did I forget some configuration or something else?

This is how my documents look like:

The Booking-Document:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Booking
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="\AppBundle\Document\Customer")
     */
    private $customer;

    // getter and setter...
}
```

The Customer-Document

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Customer
{
    // fields, getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Try with `@MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Customer")` instead.

Comment: Do `CTRL+F` and look for `mongo` [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/symfony) for symfony+mongodb examples. e.g. [Simple doctrine mongodb example for EmbedOne in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/aefp/simple-doctrine-mongodb-example-for-embed-one-in-symfony)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear your cache. Mapping is OK since the data is persisted correctly, what is wrong is that `Hydrator` was already in place and wasn't updated with the new field. To avoid such situations you can consider using [`AUTOGENERATE_EVAL`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/2db3cf94c1bc39799626e0d7ce9684916e327e6d/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Configuration.php#L86) strategy for hydrators/proxies auto-generation during the development.

Comment: Thank you. This problem was caused because of the cache.