# Doctrine mongodb type raw return NULL

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I've got a Document with Field type raw :

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="raw")
*/
private $rows;
```

I create new Document and ->setRows();
In mongodb the json object seems to be correct :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591c575a2620e16f198b456b"),
    "name" : "Layout A",
    "rows" : [ 
        {
            "sections" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Header",
                    "width" : "col-xs-12",
                    "id" : ObjectId("591c575a2620e16f198b4567")
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "sections" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Body",
                    "width" : "col-xs-8",
                    "id" : ObjectId("591c575a2620e16f198b4568")
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "Sidebar",
                    "width" : "col-xs-4",
                    "id" : ObjectId("591c575a2620e16f198b4569")
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "sections" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "Footer",
                    "width" : "col-xs-12",
                    "id" : ObjectId("591c575a2620e16f198b456a")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When i try to get the object in my Controller :

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$layout = $dm->getRepository('AppBundle:Layout')->find($id);
```

I get the rigth object with the right field except for rows that is always NULL.

Where i'm wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: If you have added field recently try clearing your cache

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43869685/5982920 for an explanation why cache may be the issue and how to get rid of it

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the cache